# How to handle the height of tableviewCell dynamically in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uistoryboard

[image]

It's what I made now! I'm newbie for iOS development.

What I want to make is the newsfeed(cardViewUI) like Facebook, but according to my design of cell, when texts are long more than capacity of label(cell's text container), it shows '..' like you see above.

So I want to increase my cell's height dynamically set by length of texts.

I designed it with mainstoryboard not .xib file. I try to [label sizeToFit] and set label's lines to 0 but nothing works so far.

Comment: Nothing wrong with what you've done. You just need to set constraints in the `contentView` of the cell so that the label shrinks / grows vertically as the content changes. Also, set the number of lines to `0` for automatic lines. Then you need to set the `rowHeight` property on the Tableview to `UITableViewAutomaticDimension ` and `estimatedHeight` on the TableView in the Storyboard. The remove your `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the text height as below,

```
//Height For Row at index path
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *cellText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[arrFullChat[indexPath.row]objectAtIndex:1]];
    UIFont *cellFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:15.0];

    NSAttributedString *attributedText =
    [[NSAttributedString alloc]
     initWithString:cellText
     attributes:@
     {
     NSFontAttributeName: cellFont
     }];
    CGRect rect = [attributedText boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(tableView.bounds.size.width - 90.0, CGFLOAT_MAX)
                                               options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                               context:nil];
    return rect.size.height + 42;
}
```

42 in this code will be vary to you. Try it with different values.

Don't forget to increase your `UITextView` height according to the `Cell` height using Autolayout or any other way you want.

Comment: hmm... if i set value 42 to another, it means it's not dynamic isn't it??... And unfortunately not working... cell's height is weird value... and i don't know why you subtract 90 from tableview.bounds.size.width! can you explain me?

Comment: I subtract 90 because my TextView is 90 pixels less than the width of the cell. You can change it as you want.

Comment: But fianlly, that method returns height value. so i think that( width value) doesn't affect right?

Comment: In your case subtracting that value is not necessary because your textView has the same size of cell. Now your App working fine???

Comment: One more thing about value 42! when i set that value 42, my tableview goes wrong. so i changed it for different values . suddenly when i set threshold value, tableview became as what i want to. what is the logic? why does that threshold value makes it right?

Comment: that 42 means the cell height without the dynamic textView. rect.size.height gives you the size of textView only

Answer (score 1):

Using `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` you can give the size of each row at run time. now your problem is how to get height from your string there are function in NSString class by this code your problem,

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  NSString *str = [dataSourceArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    CGSize size = [str sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:17] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(280, 999) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
    NSLog(@"%f",size.height);
    return size.height + 10;
}
```

by below line you set your label`s num. of line to max. so set it in`cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method.

```
cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
```

> if you use some custom cell then manage all label`s string with this
>   and get sum of all that height then set the height of your cell.

Comment: Thank you for your sincerity! I have a question. As your code, the return value of method heightForRowAtIndexPath is ‘size.height+10’. value 10 is what you set. But that value makes tableview go wrong! so i changed that value largely(because cell is shrinks too much unregularly) so when I reached some value, that makes tableview go right! What’s the reason for it? can you explain?

Comment: value 10 is used for presentation purpose.you have already mention in your comment `because cell is shrinks too much unregularly`.